# fancybox 2 - Reload the page

Tags: jquery, callback, fancybox

I just update my version of fancybox and I noticed that the rafraichisement the parent page does not work. Before I did:

```
OnClosed: function () {
    parent.location.reload (true);
}
```

But how to do it today?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

#### Callback

```
afterClose: function() {
    window.location.reload()
}
```

#### Working example

```
// Tested and works as expected 
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterClose: function() {
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

The `afterClose` callback is Called after closing animation has ended. By the way: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs